# .htaccess Is Not working in Linux (Debian) apache2 (Google Cloud)

Tags: .htaccess, google-cloud-platform, debian, .htpasswd

I know this topic has been discussed to death but I still don't see directions on how to debug this problem. I know the .htaccess file is being read because I added some gibberish to it and that broke the site. I also created the .htpasswd file. The problem is that the site is not requiring a username and password. How do I go about debugging this problem?

This is what is in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

This is what is in `/var/www/html/.htaccess`:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Área restrita"
AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
require valid-user
```

I don't have another `vHost`. This is the only virtual machine I have which is the one where the site is hosted.
The `DocumentRoot` is specified in these files as shown below:

```
sites-available/000-default.conf:       DocumentRoot /var/www/html
sites-available/default-ssl.conf:       DocumentRoot /var/www/html
```

I placed another `.htaccess` file in `/usr/lib/cgi-bin` which is exactly the same as in `/var/www/html`. The purpose is to protect the perl scripts.

The URL is [http://recordspreservation.org](http://www.recordspreservation.org)

I am also trying for now to limit access to my website with this directive. I am not sure if this has an impact on the `.htaccess` issue:

```
<Location />
    Require ip 107.217.8.189
</Location>
```

These are the `Directory` containers I found on `/etc/apache2`. Most of them are default (i.e. I haven't changed them). The one I may have a concern is `/home/*/public_html`

```
conf-available/gitweb.conf:               <Directory /usr/share/gitweb>
conf-available/gitweb.conf:               </Directory>
conf-available/javascript-common.conf:    <Directory "/usr/share/javascript/">
conf-available/javascript-common.conf:    </Directory>
conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf:        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf:        </Directory>
conf-enabled/gitweb.conf:                 <Directory /usr/share/gitweb>
conf-enabled/gitweb.conf:                 </Directory>
conf-enabled/javascript-common.conf:      <Directory "/usr/share/javascript/">
conf-enabled/javascript-common.conf:      </Directory>
conf-enabled/serve-cgi-bin.conf:          <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
conf-enabled/serve-cgi-bin.conf:          </Directory>
mods-available/alias.conf:                <Directory "/usr/share/apache2/icons">
mods-available/alias.conf:                </Directory>
mods-available/userdir.conf:              <Directory /home/*/public_html>
mods-available/userdir.conf:              </Directory>
mods-enabled/alias.conf:                  <Directory "/usr/share/apache2/icons">
mods-enabled/alias.conf:                  </Directory>
sites-available/default-ssl.conf:         <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
sites-available/default-ssl.conf:         </Directory>
```

The result of command `sudo apachectl -M | grep auth`

```
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 authn_core_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authz_core_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe, by starting reading the official documentation? Or telling us what it is not working. On apache configuration you can select that option can be overwritten (and from where). We lack information, so we cannot help. And possibly it is not a programming question.

Comment: "/etc/apache2/apache2.conf" - is this the relevant config? Do you have a separate vHost? Just a slight oddity from what you've posted is you have a `<Directory>` container for `/var/www/`, but the `.htaccess` file is in `/var/www/html/`? What is the `DocumentRoot`? Are there any more specific `<Directory>` containers? Any other `.htaccess` files? What URL are you requesting?

Comment: Do you have any other directives in this `.htaccess` file? I would try a simple `Require all denied` instead of your current directives - is access blocked?

Comment: The comment from MrWhite will probably help you debug your problem. The details your have provided appear correct. Add the configuration for `<Directory /var/www/html>` to your post. Reboot the system. Then run `apachectl -M | grep auth`. Add the command and output to your question. To be consistent change `require` to `Require`. Directives are case-insensitive, but be consistent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am also trying for now to limit access to my website with this
> directive. I am not sure if this has impact on the .htaccess issue:
>
> ```
> <Location />
>     Require ip 107.217.8.189
> </Location>
> ```

It's not clear whether you had these directives initially or this is something you've added since, but yes, these will indeed have an "impact".

This will effectively override the HTTP authentication directives in the `.htaccess` file and grant access for your IP. You will not be prompted for username/password since access has been granted by other means.

`<Location>` sections are merged *after* `<Directory>` and `.htaccess` sections.

If you want to enforce both, so *you* (from your IP address) are prompted for username/password (and users from other IPs are simply blocked) then you can perhaps add `AuthMerging And` to the `<Location>` block (the default is `Off`). For example:

```
<Location />
    AuthMerging And
    Require ip 107.217.8.189
</Location>
```

This ensures the authorization logic is combined with that of the nearest predecessor. Although this does assume that the `.htaccess` file in question is the nearest predecessor; which it may not be.